# Primitive array vs. Array template in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, primitive-types

I got this question from the cracking the coding interview book. I was able to write this method in python and java. But when I tried to write it in c++, the compiler starts yelling at me. I think the problem is that in the main function, I had a array instantiated by a template but the function is taking in a primitive array. How should I instantiate a primitive array?

```
// Given a sorted array of positive integers with an empty spot (zero) at the
// end, insert an element in sorted order. 
bool sortSortedArray(size_t arrInt[], size_t x)
{
    size_t indexArr{0};

    size_t insertNum{x};

    while (x != 0) {

        if (x < arrInt[indexArr]) {
            size_t swapVal = arrInt[indexArr];
            arrInt[indexArr];
            insertNum = swapVal;
            ++indexArr;
        }


    }

    return true;

}

// Test the sortSortedArray function.
int main()
{
    array<size_t, 5> testArr{1, 4, 5, 8, 0};

    if (sortSortedArray(testArr, 3)) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::array` and built-in arrays are entirely separate types.

Comment: Generally it is asking for issues to define a function with one type of parameter and call it with an entirely different type of parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Either make `testArr` a primitive array:

```
int testArr[] = {1, 4, 5, 8, 0};
```

or call `data()` to get the underlying array:

```
if (sortSortedArray(testArr.data(), 3)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

// this is a function template because each std::array<> parameter set creates a
// a type and we need a function for each type (we know std::size_t is the element
// type so this is only parameterized on the size)
template<size_t ArrSize>
void sortSortedArray(
    std::array<std::size_t, ArrSize>& arr,
    const std::size_t insertNum)
{
    // last position is known to be "empty"
    arr[arr.size() - 1] = insertNum;

    // swap value in last position leftwards until value to the left is less
    auto pos = arr.size() - 1;
    if (pos == 0)
        return;
    while (arr[pos - 1] > arr[pos])
    {
        const auto tmp = arr[pos - 1];
        arr[pos - 1] = arr[pos];
        arr[pos] = tmp;
        --pos;
        if (pos == 0)
            return;
    }
}

template<typename T, size_t N>
void printArray(const std::array<T, N>& r)
{
    for (const auto i : r)
    {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::array<std::size_t, 5> testArr{{1, 4, 5, 8, 0}};

    printArray(testArr);
    sortSortedArray(testArr, 3);
    printArray(testArr);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was quite busy at the time preparing for an interview. But it really helped at the time.

Comment: No problem. You can also accept this answer and even upvote if this was helpful. ;)